# Can I skip the second segment of a one way flight?

Tags: air-travel, hidden-city-ticketing

I'm planning to take a trip from Los Angeles to Houston, and found the ticket price is too high. However, I found a flight Los Angeles to Dallas/Fort Worth with a stop in Houston (LAX-IAH-DFW) that is more than $200 bucks less than the non-stop flight. Since I won't have any checked bags, can I just skip the IAH-DFW segment? What kind of problems could I run into if I do so (like being placed on the blacklist, shutting down my frequent traveler program, being charged for price difference, fine, etc.)? It's United I'm planning to take.

Comment: Is this part of a round-trip ticket? If so, the biggest and most immediate problem is that your flight home will be cancelled.

Comment: @ZachLipton It is a oneway flight.

Comment: @Moo Yeah sounds like such thing is prohibited. Thank you. Then can I go to the kiosk to cancel the second segment so that I won't be punished?

Comment: @PacmanKXking sure, but then they will re-ticket you for the more expensive single segment flight, which you should have bought in the first place :) Hidden city ticketing is set up the way it is because of the way the different passengers bear the costs of the segment - the longer flight may be cheaper than a flight to the intermediate stop because that cost is borne by the lower number of passengers wanting the intermediate stop...